# How to write paragraph template to add tags and css classes?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I have a paragraph bundle (pr_bnd1), which has several fields as below:

1. field_txt
2. field_bg_clr (list field whose key values are mapped to a css class)
3. field_font_clr (list field whose key values are mapped to a css class)

The an example output

```
<div> field_txt value</div>
```

Desired output

```
<div class="field_font_clr_value">.
   <span class="field_bg_clr_value"> field_txt value</span>
</div>
```

How would i achieve the desired results? I am having trouble getting the template file to work. Any thought?

My paragraph bundle name is "pr_bg_font_clr".

So i imagine i would have to write a template file with the name of "paragraph-items--pr-bg-font-clr", but i am not sure what the structure should be and which fields i can utilize.

Comment: version, please.

Comment: @VishalKumar the paragraph version is 7.x-1.0-rc4. Drupal core is 7.43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2532824) for the naming

> The default paragraphs template is in paragraphs-item.tpl.php. It uses
>   theme suggestions for other templates, the following suggestions are
>   available:
>
> - paragraphs__[view_mode] (e.g. paragraphs--default.tpl.php)
> - paragraphs__[type] (e.g. paragraphs--image.tpl.php)
> - paragraphs__[type]__[view_mode] (e.g. paragraphs--image--default.tpl.php)

As this seems to be wrong .. Try the suggestion:

```
paragraphs-items--pr_bg_font_clr.tpl.php
paragraphs-item--pr_bg_font_clr.tpl.php
```

Comment: thank you for the help! That seemed to work and I also used Devel to help me get the correct fields.